# Why doesn't iTunes connect provide an option for inviting testers?

Tags: ios, xamarin, app-store-connect

I have uploaded two separate builds of my app to no avail. I have both an internal tester (me) and several external testers added to the app in general, but they don't show up on the pre-release build page. This is what the relevant portion of the pre-release build page looks like:

[image: No Testers Allowed]

Has anyone else dealt with this issue?

Comment: It's ridiculously unintuitive but you have to go to Users & Roles in iTunes connect to add both internal & external testers.

Comment: The screenshot you see above was taken after I had done that.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into similar issues. There's a couple of things to check:

1) If your app has is currently not in the AppStore it needs to be 64bit.

2) You may have to manually specify a Beta Testing Entitlement:

[image: entitlements.plist]

Supposedly if you created your provisioning profile recently you shouldn't have to specify this entitlement, but I've found this isn't always the case.

Comment: The app is set to build as a universal app which I think is by default 64bit. As for your second note, I tried that but could no longer deploy to my device with the setting beta-reports-active set to yes. I also created and downloaded a new ad-hoc distribution provisioning profile signed with my production distribution cert. I have upped the build number and will try again with a new build.

Comment: Yeah. You can't deploy locally to device with the entitlement activated, but if you activate it when you upload to TestFlight the app will install and run from TF no problem.